# Which weapons do full damage from the back rank?

Tags: etrian-odyssey-untold

I know that guns and bows do full damage if used from the back rank, but for instance an axe does not. With the ability to change allowed weapon types with grimoires, there's a possibility that I might be better off moving one of my front liners to the back line, if I can equip him with a weapon that still does full damage and doesn't lock out any of his skills.

Which weapon categories do full damage from the back line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All ranged attack deal full damage from the back rank, whether it's a skill or a regular attack. The only weapons this includes are the Bow and Gun, so if you want to move one of your front line fighters to the back you'll need to equip them with one of those.

Comment: Darn. Was really hoping Spear was included.